# PHP not detecting radio inputs

Tags: php, html

**QUESTION**

why does my php code not detect the radio inputs?

I have made a submit form with radio inputs as a part of the form. But the mail is sent blank on where the radio input value should be.

This has worked before but for some reason this isn't working...

You can see the code I have down below.

Any help would be awesome!!

**PHP**

```
    // Only process POST reqeusts.

  $name = $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$tilaustyyppi = $_POST["tilaustyyppi"];
$autotyyppi = $_POST["autotyyppi"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Set the recipient email address.
$recipient = "jarkko@jarkkosalo.com";

// Set the email subject.
$subject = "Uusi tilaus $name";

// Build the email content.
$email_content = "Nimi: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Puhelin: $phone\n";
$email_content .= "Sposti: $email\n";
$email_content .= "Päivämäärä: $date\n\n";
$email_content .= "Tilaustyyppi: $tilaustyyppi\n";
$email_content .= "Autotyyppi: $autotyyppi\n\n";
$email_content .= "Viesti:\n$message\n";

// Build the email headers.
$email_headers = "Toimittanut: $name <$email>";

// Send the email.
mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)



?>
```

**HTML**

```
<h6 class="mb-15">Tilaustyyppi<span>(Vaaditaan)</span></h6>
<div class="form-group form-group-flex col-12">
<input
    type="radio"
    name="tilaustyyppi"
    id="Niin pian kuin mahdollista"
    value="Niin pian kuin mahdollista"
    required=""
    aria-required="true"
/>
<label for="Niin pian kuin mahdollista">
    Niin pian kuin mahdollista</label
>

<input
    type="radio"
    name="tilaustyyppi"
    id="Ennakkotilaus"
    value="Ennakkotilaus"
    required=""
    aria-required="true"
/>
<label for="Ennakkotilaus">Ennakkotilaus</label>
</div>

<h6 class="mb-15">Autotyyppi</h6>
<div class="form-group form-group-flex col-12">
<input
    type="radio"
    name="autotyyppi"
    id="Henkilöauto"
    value="Henkilöauto"
/>
<label for="Henkilöauto"> Henkilöauto</label>

<input
    type="radio"
    name="autotyyppi"
    id="Tilataksi-6"
    value="Tilataksi 6:lle"
/>
<label for="Tilataksi-6"> Tilataksi 6:lle</label>

<input
    type="radio"
    name="autotyyppi"
    id="Tilataksi-8"
    value="Tilataksi 8:lle"
/>
<label for="Tilataksi-8"> Tilataksi 8:lle</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your html ?

Comment: yes, it was missing

Comment: `$email_headers = "Toimittanut: $name <$email>";` is no valid header.